# Is it valid to have inside an html element another html element?

Tags: html, xslt

By valid I mean: will browsers and email clients correctly display the file.

We have a program that sends out an email formatted in HTML. The program generates the HTML using a master template and a child template.

Here's a reduced example of the generated HTML. Notice it has an 2nd HTML element inside a td element. The inner HTML has a head element but no body element (where the body is expected to be there is an td element.)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charSET="utf-8"/>
        <style type="text/css"> lots of css here </style>
    </head>
    <body >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="mainContentContainer">
                                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
                                <html xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" >
                                <head>
                                    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                                    <style type="text/css">  lots of css here </style>
                                </head>
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                </html> 
                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="20">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a complete example

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charSET="utf-8"/>
        <style type="text/css">  
        h1 {   font:normal 1.7em/1.2em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   margin:20px 0;   color:#444   }  
        h2 {   font:normal 1.4em/1.1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   margin:20px 0;   color:#444   }  
        h3 {   font:normal 1.3em/1.1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   margin:20px 0;   color:#444   }  
        h4 {   font:normal 1.2em/1.1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   margin:20px 0;   color:#444   }   
        h5 {   font:normal 1.1em/1.1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   margin:20px 0;   color:#444   }   
        h6 {   font:normal 1em/1.1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   margin:20px 0;   color:#444   }   
        p {   font:normal 0.9em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   margin:20px 0;   color:#444   }   
        data {   font:normal 0.9em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   color:#444   }   
        ol {   margin:20px 0;   }   
        ol li {   font:normal 0.9em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   margin:0;   padding:0 0 0 20px;   color:#444   }   
        ul {   margin:20px 0   }   ul li {   font:normal 0.9em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   margin:0;   padding:0 0 0 20px;   color:#444   }   
        hr {   width:100%;   height:1px;   color:#cccccc;   background:#cccccc;   border: 0;   }  </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#dadada">
        <table width="641" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table width="601" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <td height="20">
                                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b8/1d/55/b81d55c10b9a7769b550a85148ed32d7.png" width="601" height="20" alt="Spacer"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="146">
                                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b8/1d/55/b81d55c10b9a7769b550a85148ed32d7.png" width="609" height="146" alt="picture"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="20">
                                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b8/1d/55/b81d55c10b9a7769b550a85148ed32d7.png" width="601" height="20" alt="Spacer"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#f7f7f7">
                                <table width="601" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:1px solid #dadada">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td bgcolor="#f7f7f7" style=" border-bottom:1px solid #dadada" valign="top">
                                            <table width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td id="mainContentContainer"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
                                                        <html xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" >
                                                            <head>
                                                                <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                                                                <style type="text/css">   
                                                                h4 {    font: normal 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;    margin: 5px 0;    color: #333;   }   
                                                                table tr th {    padding: 5px 0;   }   
                                                                table tr th,   
                                                                table tr td {    font: normal 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;    color: #333;   }   
                                                                p {    margin: 5px 0;   }   
                                                                hr {    width: 100%;    height: 1px;    color: #cccccc;    background: #cccccc;    border: 0;    margin: 5px 0;    padding: 0;   }  
                                                                table.tableWithBorders th {    border: 1px solid DimGray;    padding: 5px;    padding-top: 0px;   }   
                                                                table.tableWithBorders td {    border: 1px solid DimGray;    padding: 5px;    padding-bottom: 0px;   }   
                                                                table.tableWithBorders {    border-collapse: collapse;   }   
                                                                table.tableWithBorders tr:first-child th {    border-top: 0;   }   
                                                                table.tableWithBorders tr:last-child td {    border-bottom: 0;   }   
                                                                table.tableWithBorders tr td:first-child,   table.tableWithBorders tr th:first-child {    border-left: 0;   }   
                                                                table.tableWithBorders tr td:last-child,   table.tableWithBorders tr th:last-child {    border-right: 0;   }  </style>
                                                            </head>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <table width="550" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="text-align:right">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <br/>
                                                                            <p>some text.</p>
                                                                            <p>some more text</p>
                                                                            <p>some moretext</p>
                                                                            <p style="padding-top:5px">      12345</p>
                                                                            <p style="padding-top:5px">      abcdef</p>
                                                                            <p>
                                                                                <a href="https://www.apple.com" target="_blank" style="color: #333;">www.apple.com</a>
                                                                            </p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                                <table width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <br/>
                                                                            <p>
                                                                                <strong>some text: </strong>abcd1234</p>
                                                                            <p>
                                                                                <strong>abcdefghi</strong>1234</p>
                                                                            <br/>
                                                                            <p>abcdefghi</p>
                                                                            <p>abcdefghi</p>
                                                                            <p>abcdefghi</p>
                                                                            <p>abcdefghi</p>
                                                                            <p/>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                                <h4 style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                                                    <strong>abcdefghi</strong>
                                                                </h4>
                                                                <hr width="100%"/>
                                                                <div style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                                                                    <p>
                                                                        <strong>abcdefghi: </strong>abcdefghi.</p>
                                                                    <p>
                                                                        <strong>abcdefghi: </strong>0.00</p>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <table class="tableWithBorders" width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <th style="text-align: left;">
                                                                            <p>
                                                                                <strong>abcdefghi</strong>
                                                                            </p>
                                                                        </th>
                                                                        <th style="text-align: right;">
                                                                            <p>
                                                                                <strong>         abcdefghi        </strong>
                                                                            </p>
                                                                        </th>
                                                                        <th style="text-align: right;">
                                                                            <p>
                                                                                <strong>abcdefghi</strong>
                                                                            </p>
                                                                        </th>
                                                                        <th style="text-align: right;">
                                                                            <p>
                                                                                <strong>         abcdefghi        </strong>
                                                                            </p>
                                                                        </th>
                                                                        <th style="text-align: right;">
                                                                            <p>
                                                                                <strong>         abcdefghi        </strong>
                                                                            </p>
                                                                        </th>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <p>abcdefghi</p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                                                                            <p>0.00</p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                                                                            <p>0        </p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                                                                            <p>0.00</p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="text-align:right;">
                                                                            <p>0.00</p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                                <table width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td colspan="5">
                                                                            <hr width="100%"/>
                                                                            <div style="clear: both;"/>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <p>
                                                                                <strong>abcdefghi:</strong>
                                                                            </p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="text-align:right;">
                                                                            <p>
                                                                                <strong>0.00</strong>
                                                                            </p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td colspan="5">
                                                                            <hr width="100%"/>
                                                                            <div style="clear: both;"/>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                                <table class="tableWithBorders" width="350" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-top:20px;">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <th style="text-align: left;">
                                                                            <p>
                                                                                <strong>abcdefghi</strong>
                                                                            </p>
                                                                        </th>
                                                                        <th style="text-align: right;">
                                                                            <p>
                                                                                <strong>abcdefghi</strong>
                                                                            </p>
                                                                        </th>
                                                                        <th style="text-align: right;">
                                                                            <p>
                                                                                <strong>abcdefghi</strong>
                                                                            </p>
                                                                        </th>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <p>      abcdefghi     </p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                                                                            <p>0.00</p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                                                                            <p>0.00</p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <p>     abcdefghi     </p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                                                                            <p>0.00</p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                                                                            <p>0.00</p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <p>      abcdefghi     </p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                                                                            <p>0.00</p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                                                                            <p>0.00</p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <p>     abcdefghi     </p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                                                                            <p>0.00</p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: right;">
                                                                            <p>0.00</p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td style="border-top-width:2px;">
                                                                            <p>      abcdefghi   </p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: right;border-top-width:2px;"/>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: right;border-top-width:2px;">
                                                                            <p>0.00</p>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                                <table width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <p>abcdefghi</p>
                                                                            <p>abcdefghi</p>
                                                                            <div style="clear: both;"/>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </html>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td height="146">
                                                        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b8/1d/55/b81d55c10b9a7769b550a85148ed32d7.png" width="601" height="200" alt="picture"/>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="top">
                                            <table width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="font:11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding:15px 0; color:#444" valign="top">       abcdefghi.<br/>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="20">
                    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b8/1d/55/b81d55c10b9a7769b550a85148ed32d7.png" width="641" height="20" alt="Spacer"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The master template looks like this (simplified)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charSET="utf-8"/>
        <style type="text/css"> </style>
    </head>
    <body >
        <table >
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table >
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table >
                                    <tr>
                                        <td >
                                            <table >
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td id="mainContentContainer"/>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="20">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the code the mainContentContainer is replaced with the child template. The child template is generated by passing XML through XSLT. Here is a very simplified example.

```
<xsl:stylesheet>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                <style type="text/css">  </style>
            </head>
            <td>
                <table >
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <br/>
                            <p>
                                <xsl:value-of select=""/>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <xsl:value-of select=""/>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <xsl:value-of select=""/>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table >
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <br/>
                            <p>
                                <strong>some text: </strong>
                                <xsl:value-of select=""/>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>        
            </td>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Well, decide of which version of (X)HTML you want to validate with and use a validator to check but a single HTML document has a single `html` root element and no contained `html` elements; and in terms of XML you can't put a second XML declaration either somewhere in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your markup fragment doesn't contain valid HTML. An embedded `html` and `meta` element is disallowed according to WHATWG's HTML content model for `dt` which reads

> Flow content, but with no header, footer, sectioning content, or heading content descendants

(cf. chapter 4.4.10 of the current WHATWG spec at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/ or the SGML DTD distilled from it at https://sgmljs.net/docs/whatwg-html200129-dtd.html).

HTML email is especially picky and is generally expected to use only the subset of HTML and CSS constructs supported by MS Outlook 2007.

Moreover, not only is an XML declaration invalid other than at the begin of an XML document (which yours isn't supposed to be since you want HTML not XHTML), but your XSLT output isn't producing HTML serialization in the first place as is evident by bogus XML-style empty elements (ie. using an improper slash in the `meta` element/tag).

Try putting

```
<xsl:output method="html"/>
```

as first instruction into your XSLT.

Then try using an XPath selector for selecting just the `tr` part in your template. As it is, it looks like you're selecting "everything" (the document root) from an external document, but it's difficult to tell.

Your external document *appears* to be half-valid HTML with the start- and end-element tags for `body` omitted (which is valid in HTML/SGML but not XML). If so, you can use SGML to produce proper XHTML; see eg. https://sgmljs.net/docs/parsing-html-tutorial/parsing-html-tutorial.html.